# IFELSE statement how does this work to IF then Else

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-objects

I have a condition in Business Objects which I am trying to replicate in IDT Universe.

It goes like this.. it's an `IFELSE` statement, I have not used before.

```
IFELSE ("Line1" IS NUll, IFELSE("Line2" IS NULL, 'APT', 'NA'), 'Line1')
```

This format throws error

> [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server]: 'ifElse' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How this can be changed.

Is this correct?

```
IF "Line1" IS NOT NULL THEN 'LINE1' ELSE
IF "LINE2" IS NOT NULL THEN 'NA" ELSE 'APT'
```

Thank You for your time.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, `IFSELSE` isn't a T-SQL function. You want the `IIF` function, or a `CASE` expression.

Comment: `case when "Line1" is not null then 'Line1' when "Line2" is not null then 'NA' else 'APT' end`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, there is no `IFELSE` function in T-SQL.

Instead, you can use a `CASE` expression or an `IIF()` function.

Assuming that your column is an `N/VARCHAR` datatype:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN YourColumn IS NOT NULL
            THEN YourColumn
            ELSE 'N/A'
       END UsingCaseExpression,
       IIF(YourColumn IS NOT NULL, YourColumn, 'N/A') UsingIIFFunction
FROM YourTable;
```

Further more, in your case I think you could also use `ISNULL()` function as:

```
SELECT ISNULL(YourColumn, 'N/A') UsingIsNull
FROM YourTable;
```

So, your query can be like the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Line1 IS NOT NULL
            THEN Line1
            WHEN Line1 IS NULL AND Line2 IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'NA'
            ELSE 'APT'
            END
            
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (NULL, NULL),
  ('Line1Value', 'Line2Value'),
  ('Line1SecondValue', NULL),
  (NULL, 'Line2SecondValue')
) YourTable(Line1, Line2)
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Just replace IFELSE with [IFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) and remove the quotes around your column references:

```
SELECT IIF (Line1 IS NUll, IIF(Line2 IS NULL, 'APT', 'NA'), Line1)
FROM (SELECT NULL as Line1, NULL as Line2) as example
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is indeed incorrect. Use the bottom line you write, but remove the "THEN." Your syntax should be:

```
IF "LINE1" IS NOT NULL

"LINE1"

ELSE IF "LINE2" IS NOT NULL

"NA"

ELSE 

"APT"
```

Honestly however, I prefer to use CASE instead of IF's as it makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the column values, use `COALESCE`, if you want to get some constants, use `CASE`.

You can use `COALESCE` as follows:

`COALESCE(Line1, Line2)`

This should get the contents of `Line1` if a value exists otherwise it will get the contents of `Line2`.

You can use `CASE` as follows:

`CASE WHEN Line1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Line1' ELSE (CASE WHEN Line2 IS NULL THEN 'APT' ELSE 'NA' END) END`